# Batch file with Variable directory Paths

Tags: batch-file

I have simple move command that I need to make into a batch file.

move "\company-nas\local\Shared\Sites\Property_A\Directory A" "\company-nas\local\Shared\Sites\Property_A\Directory B"

My issue is the Property_A is variable. So the next copy would be Property_B. So on and so forth. How can I make this into a batch script?

Edit:

First 2...

```
move "\\company-nas\local\Shared\Sites\Arpmanor\Directory A" "\\company-nas\local\Shared\Sites\Arpmanor\Directory B"

move "\\company-nas\local\Shared\Sites\Bailey Lane\Directory A" "\\company-nas\local\Shared\Sites\Bailey Lane\Directory B"
```

Last 2....

```
move "\\company-nas\local\Shared\Sites\Woodstream\Directory A" "\\company-nas\local\Shared\Sites\Woodstream\Directory B"

move "\\company-nas\local\Shared\Sites\Woodview\Directory A" "\\company-nas\local\Shared\Sites\Woodview\Directory B"
```

Comment: How many total properties are there? Is Directory B static?

Comment: 63 different properties.

Comment: What do you do after you get to Z? Edit your post and show the move command you want to see for the first 2 and last 2 properties.

Comment: The names of the properties are alphabetical but not logical like I have it written.  So not Property_A, B, C. etc. The name's change entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /ad "\\company-nas\local\Shared\Sites\*"') do (
echo Move "\\company-nas\local\Shared\Sites\%%a\Directory A" ^
   "\\company-nas\local\Shared\Sites\%%a\Directory B"
)
```

I added the echo in just so you can tell if the output is what you want. Remove it to do the actual moves.

(Fixed by Magoo : needed to include the directory in the `dir` - could have used a `pushd/popd` bracket, of course...)

Comment: Well it did it but flew through the lines and didn't move anything. However, if I copy 1 line and paste it as 1 command and hit enter it works and moves the directory.  It's like it read back to me what it could do but didn't execute anything.

Comment: Wow, sorry totally missed your comment and the echo before move. Thanks alot... that worked!